# HIghcharts tooltips only for start and end point.

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using a line chart with datetime information.  Everything seems to work just perfectly except that for some reason I only get the tooltip to come up for the first point and the last. Not for any in between.

I've tried fooling around with xDateFormat to no avail.

```
tooltip: {
xDateFormat: '%H:%M',
shared: true
},
```

Any suggestions?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jt7vp/

Comment: Data should be sorted ascending via x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a issue with your data. its in descending order, that has been the issue.
I've updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jt7vp/1/)

changes done in

```
series:[{data:[]},{data:[]},{data:[]}]
```

Hope this will be useful

Comment: Thank you.  I would have never guessed that was what was causing it.